# Is it normal to be crazy rude and ask irrelevant questions?

Tags: discussion, comments

[What do you call an open food vessel?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/316672/what-do-you-call-an-open-food-vessel)

The first guy asks why there's a discrepancy. Well, I couldn't find any image that perfectly fit the description. Why is he being rude to me?

> You're asking about open vessels, but the picture seems to show closed ones. Why the discrepancy? –
> MarcInManhattan
> yesterday

> @MarcInManhattan - and if they're 'conic shape' I need new eyeglasses. –
> Michael Harvey
> yesterday

And then the second guy makes a sarcastic comment. I flag it and it gets rejected. I don't know if I am crazy, but this is just ridiculous. Why don't they find a better image then? I looked for an image for 15 minute, but couldn't find a better one because I didn't know what word to use.

Comment: It might also help to add a description of what you mean by open. The image shows cylindrical containers which have an opening lid so in a certain sense they are open but I suspect you have lidless containers in mind.

Comment: "I flag it and it gets rejected." Of course it'll get rejected!!! It isn't sarcastic at all!

Comment: I'm just noticing this now. I was actually interested in answering your question but was slightly confused by the discrepancy between the question and the picture; as others have noted, my comment was a sincere effort to try to clarify the issue. There was certainly no intention to be rude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asking *good* questions is hard. And by "good" I mean a post which shows thought and effort.

Asking good interesting questions is even harder.

And as we all know asking good interesting questions in a language that is not your mother tongue is perhaps one of the most fraught experiences a non-native speaker can face.

Even native speakers can get stuck on a word but they usually possess the lexical skills that allow them to find the answer for themselves or at least give an accurate description.

The OP spent time and effort in writing their question. We can tell because they went to the trouble to find an image which describes the noun they are looking for. So, imagine finding two comments by competent native speakers that *appear* to mock your efforts, especially if you are painfully aware of the gaps in your English skills.

But the OP is mistaken to take offence regarding the first comment, it is not irrelevant, rude or mocking the question in any way. It is instead asking for clarification  by making a pertinent observation. The second comment; however, **was directed at the first commenter**. It is a glib slick response which does not help the original poster, but accentuates the lexical shortcomings of the question. Coupled that with the downvotes and the question being closed– thanks no doubt to the [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect)–we are left with a disgruntled and unsatisfied user.

Answer (score 7):

The first comment is asking for clarification; I don't see how that can be considered rude. The second comment is an attempt at a joke, it's not sarcasm.

I think both comments can go, but only *after* you've edited your question to add something like 'these aren't the containers I'm looking for, but they would be used in a similar setting'. That's what [comments are for](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), to help making the post clearer.

Comment: "The second comment is an attempt at a joke" - ouch!

Comment: ... maybe I should've written "in a way that tries to be funny"? I'm sure you meant no harm, and I might have been too direct (I'm Dutch, can't help it).